# Volume of the solid around y-axis -- 2 different methods

Tags: calculus

I wanted to take a relatively simple volume rotation around the y-axis and find the volume using a dx and also a dy method.

$y=\sqrt{(x-1)}$ and $y=(x-1)^2$

First I found the intersection of the 2 graphs at $(1,0)$ and $(2,1)$.  I then integrated to find $V = 2(\pi)rh$ $dx = 2\pi*x(\sqrt{(x-1)} - (x-1)^2)dx$
I then integrated this over the interval x=1 to x=2.  I got the book's answer of $\frac{29\pi}{30}$.  Yes!

I then wanted to integrate this across the y axis using V = pi integral (A(y) dy).

I got $\pi\int(y^2 +1- y^2 -1)^2 dy)$ integrated from $y=0$ to $y=1$, the range.
After squaring I got $\pi\int(y^4 -2y^(5/2) +y dy)$

This results in $\frac{9\pi}{70}$, a different result.

Shouldn't I be able to use either method to get the same answer?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:$$y=\sqrt{x-1}\implies y^2+1=x$$$$ y=(x-1)^2\implies \sqrt{y}+1=x$$
The volume is:$$\pi \int_0^1 (\sqrt{y}+1)^2-(y^2+1)^2dy=\frac{29}{30}\pi$$

Comment: Thank you!  I can see that my problem was squaring the subtraction, rather than subtracting the squares!  You have helped me to understand this concept, and I very much appreciate it.